# F# Script SharePoint 2010 API doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint, f#, 64-bit, f#-interactive, f#-scripting

I am trying something really simple in F# to try and test interaction with the SharePoint 2010 API.  I think I am running into a general problem with F#.  Is there anyway that an F# script can access the SharePoint 2010 API?

I think my problem is due to the F# scripts running 32bit, and the SharePoint API is in 64bit.

An example of the code I'm trying to run is as follows:

```
#r "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\Microsoft.sharepoint.dll"
#r "System.ServiceModel.dll"

open System
open Microsoft.SharePoint

let GetListByUrl (listUrl:string) =
    use site = new SPSite(listUrl)
    use web = site.OpenWeb()
    let list = 
        if not (web = null) then web.GetList(listUrl)
    list
```

In the visual studio editor it says the following error: The Type System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1 is required here and is unavailable.  You must add a reference to assembly ...

When the script is ran it gives the message:  System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The Web application at... could not be found.  Verify that you have typed the URL correctly...

Which is the error message I get if I try to access the SharePoint 2010 API from a 32bit c# console program.  If I change the c# console program to Any CPU that message doesn't appear.

However I'm trying to do this in an F# script which I guess is 32bit, so how would I work around that?

Also since this is probably a general problem with F# scripts and 64bit dlls, how would you work around the problem of needing to reference 64bit dlls in F# scripts?

**Edit**
I used corflags.exe in the visual studio cmd prompt to modify the fsi.exe to 64bit.  I followed this guide: http://ig2600.blogspot.com/2010/05/making-fsharp-interpreter-fsi-run-in.html.  That seemed to work, though the F# interactive window seemed slower.  However when I ran the code above in the now 64bit fsi it said sharepoint does not work with .net 4.0.  How would you run the F# interactive window in .net 3.5?

**Edit**
Because of the answer posted by F.Aquino in which he said I needed to add a reference to System.ServiceModel I have updated the code to add that.

That fixes the visual studio editor complaints that keep appearing with red squiggly lines everywhere.  When the script is ran the results are the same, the script cannot access the sharepoint 2010 API which is the problem I am having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a reference to System.ServiceModel

Comment: I don't know anywhere enough about .net to say for sure, but I think this is a red herring.  Adding that reference produced the same results when the script was ran.  Although the red squiggly lines in the visual studio editor did disappear.

Comment: I did manage to run something that grabs a list info but I do not use the #f-scripting for that, I'm using a normal F# Lib Project and referencing the ServiceModel assembly in the project. [edit: with visual studio 2010]